# Convert tertiles to binary by using R (dplyr)

Tags: r, dataframe, binary, dplyr

I have a large data.frame (df) like this:

```
A B C D E 
1.2 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.2 
4.2 5.3 6.5 7.2 1.5 
2 7 3 4 6 
1 2 3 4 5
```

and I wanted to create a tertile group of column B by using dplyr in R with this code:

First

```
library('dplyr')
ntile(df$B, 3)
```

so I got three groups from column B :

```
#group 1
ntile(df$B,3)==1
#group2
ntile(df$B,3)==2
#group3
ntile(df$B,3)==3
```

Now I want to generate binary variables by joining groups 1,2 to become one group and group 3 to become the second group.
I applied this code:

Second

```
#combine group1,2
bin1 <- c((ntile(df$B,3)==1),(ntile(df$B,3)==2))
#creating the second group
bin2 <- (ntile(df$B,3)==3)
```

I just want to make sure if I did it right or not (in first and second parts)? and I would like to know if there is any other (faster/easier) way to do it? by using (dplyr or any other packages in R)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**: using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(ter=ntile(B, 3), bin=ifelse(ter < 3, "low", "high"))
```

Produces:

```
    A   B   C   D   E ter  bin
1 1.2 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.2   1  low
2 4.2 5.3 6.5 7.2 1.5   2  low
3 2.0 7.0 3.0 4.0 6.0   3 high
4 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0   1  low
```

---

**OLD BASE SOLUTION**

Typically you use `cut` for this type of thing.  I'm not sure `ntile` actually does what you want:

```
df$ter <- cut(df$B, quantile(df$B, seq(0, 1, 1/3)), include.lowest=T)
df$bin <- ifelse(as.numeric(df$ter) < 3, "low", "high")
df
```

Produces:

```
    A   B   C   D   E       ter  bin
1 1.2 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.2   [2,2.2]  low
2 4.2 5.3 6.5 7.2 1.5 (2.2,5.3]  low
3 2.0 7.0 3.0 4.0 6.0   (5.3,7] high
4 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0   [2,2.2]  low
```

`cut` generates a factor that classifies each value into a bin, and here we specified the bins as terciles with the function `quantile`.  Then we took advantage of the ordered factor nature of `df$ter` to combine the first two binds into the `low` bin, and leave the third bin (hence the `< 3`) into the `high` bin.

Comment: Thanks BrodieG! It was really useful; I knew the cut function but I decided to focus on dplyr. I compared cut and ntile output and I noticed that they are similar.